# Sphinx extensions on readthedocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Recently I started using the `sphinx_autodoc_typehints` and the `sphinx_autodoc_defaultargs` extensions for Sphinx via my project's [`conf.py`](https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics/blob/master/docs/conf.py). As it seems are not default packages in the sphinx installation on readthedocs (over there sphinx is on v1.8.5). Because my build fails with an `Extension error` shown [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pybliometrics/builds/14223016/):

```
Could not import extension sphinx_autodoc_typehints (exception: No module named 
'sphinx_autodoc_typehints')
```

I understand I somehow have to tell readthedocs to get sphinx_autodoc_typehints (and later sphinx_autodoc_defaultargs as well) from PyPI. *Or is there a way I can install packages on readthedocs myself?*

Since I use `pbr` for package management I use a requirements.txt that readthedocs knows of. I don't want to specify the sphinx extensions there because every user of my package would have to install them. *Is there no other way of telling readthedocs which extensions to use?*

Comment: Yes, and you can specify which version of any package include Sphinx by using a requirements file and specifying it in your project. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/reproducible-builds.html#pinning-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment of Steve Piercy, I found a way to have two requiremens.txt. readthedocs' advanced settings (on the website) allow for one requirements.txt only.

readthedocs' preferred way are `.readthedocs.yaml`, which needs to live in the root folder. Following https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html, this is how the file now looks like:

```
version: 2

sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

python:
  version: 3.7
  install:
    - requirements: requirements.txt
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

and the `docs/requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
sphinx==3.4.3
sphinx_autodoc_typehints==1.12.0
sphinx_autodoc_defaultargs==0.1.2
```

In the advanced settings page I had to manually set the location of sphinx' `conf.py`, although it's a standard location. Without this setting my build would still fail.

Comment: Is this compatible with Conda environment (i.E. 
```conda:
  environment: environment.yml```  in readthedocs.yaml  ? It seems to fail for me

Comment: Idk, I don't use conda